# Devise Error Validations not working for Login

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, devise

I am using devise for login and signup etc.. My validations seem to work on my `sign-up` page but not my `sign-in` page. Here is what i'm using.

sessions/new.html.erb

```rails
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/devisemes' %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => :off, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Password" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% link_to "Forget Password", new_user_password_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

shared/_devisemes.html.erb

```html
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %> 

<script type="text/javascript">
<% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
toastr.error("<%= msg %>")
<% end %>
</script>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```rails
  validates :username, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16 }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :email, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum:45 }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}



  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true
```

When i click submit when its blank or doesnt match a username it just reloads the page no error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code at the end:

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:alert].present? %>
  <p><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also, have you tried simple html validation? like 
`<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Email",` **required="true"** `%>`
 or something